# Databricks Cluster Spark configuration

Tags: databricks, cluster-computing

How to run code in a Cluster's Spark Configuration. I've tried several settings to get Python to set the default database. Idea is that users don't have to specify the database when writing SQL queries. I'be tried several commands that work in the Notebooks, but, don't seem to do anything when executed in the Cluster's Spark Configuration.

spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase dbname

Command above works correctly in a Notebook.

Tried different options in the Cluster's Spark configuration, Cluster seems to run the command w/o any errors (checked the logs), but, either it's not doing anything or something is overriding this as soon as I run the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff you run in notebook and cluster config are different things.

By running `spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase` you invoke an instance method `setCurrentDatabase` of class [`Catalog`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalog/Catalog.html#setCurrentDatabase(dbName:String):Unit).

By setting cluster's Spark configuration you are attempting to use one of [Spark configuration properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), however there is no property named `spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase`, instead use `spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.defaultDatabase` (available since Spark 3.4.0).